# Expectation of the square of the difference between two dependent variables

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

I have two dependent variables $X$ and $Y$.

In the paper I am reading I see

$$
E[(X-Y)^2]=\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2-2\rho\sigma_X^2\sigma_Y^2+(E[X^2]+E[Y^2]-2E[X]E[Y]).
$$

When I try to calculate it I get

$$
\begin{align}
E[(X-Y)^2]&=E[X^2]-2E[XY]+E[Y^2]
\\&=E[X^2]+E[Y^2]-2E[X]E[Y]-2COV[X,Y]
\\&=E[X^2]+E[Y^2]-2E[X]E[Y]-2\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y
\end{align}
$$

I cannot figure out the last step. Have I made a mistake before? Many thanks.

The link to the paper is: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03524677/

Comment: Your calculation looks correct. Can you please include the link to the paper?

Comment: Are you sure the paper have $\sigma_X^2 + \ldots + E(X^2)+\ldots$ and not $\sigma_X^2 + \ldots + E(X)^2 + \ldots$?